# Does Nuxt 3 use Vite and Webpack together?

Tags: webpack, vite, nuxtjs3

I'm reading the Nuxt3 features and I noticed that Nuxt3 use two different bundlers:

- Vite
- Webpack 5

Why are necessary two different bundlers? Shouldn't Vite replace webpack?

Answer (score 4):

Nuxt3 is using Vite by default, but you can opt-in for a Webpack5 build too.
As you can see by running your dev server, it will display Vite's info + you can also quite noticeably see the speed of it.

Not sure if there is something more official than this: https://v3.nuxtjs.org/migration/overview#migrate-from-nuxt-2-to-nuxt-3

TLDR: Nuxt3 supports both, but the default is Vite.